# MsAccess counter type field v.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb6

I'm developing a vb.net program that inserts records on a MSAccess table.
The structure of the record is very simple:
Field a1 is a counter
Field b1 is a a numeric value
As you know when I insert a record I do not have to specify the counter value (a1 field) because it is calculated automatically. Generally the next value is incrementebd by 1 but, if the last inserted record is deleted, the counter value is calculated by adding the last counter value +2.
My program should show the counter value of the record before insert it in the table. How to calculate it ?
Thank you very much for your help and cooperation
regards

Comment: _My program should show the counter_  No, you shouldn't use those values for your UI

Comment: The auto increment ID is just a unique identifier.  It is of no interest to the user at all

Comment: "...if the last inserted record is deleted, the counter value is calculated by adding the last counter value +2". No it isn't.  The system knows what the last generated value was and it increments that.  Why exactly do you think you need to display this value before saving?  There can be legitimate reasons but usually people who want to do that are simply misguided and haven't considered all the implications or alternatives.

Comment: VB6 answer, but you should be able to adapt it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498221/retreve-next-autonumber-for-access-table